# why ui is changing when I just add a tag for refreshing (pull) web view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

i just wanted to give pull to referesh access in my react native webveiew app .
and i used a library called react-native-pull-to-refresh and used the tag and there i got my ui changed .
the webview was shifted down and top half was occupied by the tag 
here is the code

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
<PTRView style={{}} onRefresh={()=>{this.Gymkhana.reload()}} />


        <WebView
          source={{ uri: "http://www.gymkhana.iitkgp.ac.in/index.php" }}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
          ref={ref => (this.Gymkhana = ref)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },

});
```

please resolve my error

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be cause by the fact you are using it incorectly, you should wrap your content in the `PTRView` and not just use it as separate element. refer to doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pull-to-refresh

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <PTRView style={{}} onRefresh={()=>{this.Gymkhana.reload()}} >
          <WebView
            source={{ uri: "http://www.gymkhana.iitkgp.ac.in/index.php" }}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            startInLoadingState={true}
            renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
            ref={ref => (this.Gymkhana = ref)}
          />
        </PTRView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },

});
```

Comment: I already used it as u said then the webview is completely getting disappeared .so I used like this.

Comment: then you have to add some stiles to your view, set height either on view or the webView

Comment: it isnt working when i give height to webview . it is restricting the website height inside. can we connect on someother platform i will discuss about it detailed